# Expressing a permuation as a product of disjoint cycles.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The theorem:

> *Let $p$ be a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then $p$ can be expressed as a product of disjoint cycles.*

How would you express a permutation that permutes every element of the set, as a product of disjoint cycles?

For example how would you express the permutation:

$p_1=(1 2 3 4 5 \ldots n)$ as a product of disjoint cycles?

Comment: Your permutation is itself a cycle, so it is already a "product of disjoint cycles"

Comment: Proper MathJax code is \{1,\ldots,n\}, which appears like this: $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, or like this: $$ \{1,\ldots,n\}.$$  The $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ are _inside_ the MathJax code. I edited the question accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So having one cycle counts as a "product of disjoint cycles"?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks

Comment: Is the question about how to write a general permutation as a product of disjoint cycles, or just a confusion about if there's only one term in the product? The latter was already answered; for the former, just "follow" a given element under the permutation to make a cycle, then start another one with an element not in that first cycle if there are any and repeat.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in a comment, $p_1$ is already exhibited as a product of disjoint cycles, in this case one cycle. A product of one factor is, by the way, not the extreme case of a product; there is also the [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product), the identity element. Whereas evaluating the empty product requires you to know the identity element, a product with a single factor simply evaluates to that factor.

Comment: Thanks. I think it was just the use of the word "cycles" that threw me off.